# How can you pull data from multiple variables from a button that opens a bootstrap modal?

Tags: javascript, jquery

The my-link2 and mylink3 aren't pulling in any data for some reason.  They show undefined.  So I am not sure what I am doing wrong?

Button:

```
    <input class='btn btn-default' 
    data-mylink=\"$row[auditID]\"
    data-mylink2=\"$audit_type\"
    data-mylink3=\"$row[audit_instanceID]\"
    type=button 
    data-toggle='modal' 
    data-target='#perform_audit'
    value='Take Audit' />
```

Jquery:

```
$('#perform_audit').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
        var btn = $(e.relatedTarget);
        var auditID = btn.data('mylink');
        var audittype = btn.data('mylink2');
        var auditinstanceID = btn.data('mylink3');

        $('#editfindings_audit1').text(auditID); 
        $('#editfindings_audit1').text(audittype);
        $('#editfindings_audit1').text(auditinstanceID);

        alert(auditID + " : "+audittype+ " : " + audittype);
        $('#editfindings_audit1').load("answer_audit.php?auditID="+auditID+"&audit_type="+audittype+"&action=answer&audit_instanceID="+auditinstanceID);
        //answer_audit.php?auditID=214&action=answer&audit_instanceID=572   
        //alert(auditID +" 0"+ audittype +" 0" +auditinstanceID); 
        //window.open("answer_audit.php?auditID="+auditID+"&audit_type="+audittype+"&action=answer&audit_instanceID="+auditinstanceID)
});//End [Take Audit] button
```

Comment: You've almost certainly checked already, but if not: check that the values you are passing into the data attribute are actually what you expect them to be and not empty/undefined/null whatever.

Comment: Yes, I do have data that is there.

Comment: Also check the `$(e.relatedTarget)` is the actual button.

Comment: it showed me [object Object]

Comment: $('#editfindings_audit1').text(auditID); 
        $('#editfindings_audit1').text(audittype);
        $('#editfindings_audit1').text(auditinstanceID);  These were the problem!

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use `.attr()` instead of `.data()`. Try this:

```
$('#perform_audit').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
        var btn = $(e.relatedTarget);
        var auditID = btn.attr('data-mylink');
        var audittype = btn.attr('data-mylink2');
        var auditinstanceID = btn.attr('data-mylink3');

        $('#editfindings_audit1').text(auditID); 
        $('#editfindings_audit1').text(audittype);
        $('#editfindings_audit1').text(auditinstanceID);

        alert(auditID + " : "+audittype+ " : " + audittype);
        $('#editfindings_audit1').load("answer_audit.php?auditID="+auditID+"&audit_type="+audittype+"&action=answer&audit_instanceID="+auditinstanceID);
        //answer_audit.php?auditID=214&action=answer&audit_instanceID=572   
        //alert(auditID +" 0"+ audittype +" 0" +auditinstanceID); 
        //window.open("answer_audit.php?auditID="+auditID+"&audit_type="+audittype+"&action=answer&audit_instanceID="+auditinstanceID)
});//End [Take Audit] button
```

Comment: Since the OP is talking about `undefined`, changing to `attr()` sounds like bad advice.